Error while getting content stream from OpenAi API
const Response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-0125",
    stream: true,
    messages: updatedChat
});



for await (const chunk of Response) {
    process.stdout.write(chunk.choices[0]?.delta?.content || "");
}

Error:
Possible unhandled promise rejection

TypeError: Object is not async iterable

I'm trying to get the message stream back from the API, I am using react native expo. Building a clientside project and trying to fetch data from a tsx file directly from the user side.

Did you add async on the method which run this ?

Yes i did.                                     const Response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-0125",
stream:true,
messages: updatedChat
});
for await (const chunk of Response) {
process.stdout.write(chunk.choices[0]?.delta?.content || "");
}
Porssible unhandeled promise rejection
error:TypeError: Object is not async iterable

do you know it should be like async method() { await thing(); } ?

Removing the last await may work
